# Autofilter column based on criteria - number of digits

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

So far I have tried different `autofilter` options in but non seems to be working for me, I have license number column which should only have 10 digits in it and by `autofilter` I am trying to find entries which has less than or more than 10 digits,

I converted that column to text filed in order to use

**`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BN$235").AutoFilter Field:=12,  Criteria1:="<>*??????????*"'`**

But this doesn't seems to be working as it gives me all the entries including **`<> &= 10 digits`**,

I also tried
    **``` criteria ``">"10000000000"' &<90000000000 ```**

This also is not working (I changed column to Number filed to match the criteria)    can I get any help on whats wrong I am doing here so I can rectify it

Comment: Build a dictionary so the keys can be used as criteria or add a helper column.

Comment: @Jeeped thank you i shall try this, i also want to know why                           Criteria1:="<>*??????????*" is not working even when i converted criteria range to text format

Comment: It probably has to do with the `*` wildcard being anything and everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Criteria1` and `Criteria2` with `Operator:=xlAnd`.

```
with ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BN$235")
    .AutoFilter Field:=12,  Criteria1:=">999999999", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<10000000000"
end with
```

Comment: i did try this with And/or operator, the result i am getting is based on mathematics value i.e it gives me numbers like 1010101010 (>999999999),
4231597657 (<10000000000) which are mathematically correct since both meet criteria of being < or > 10000000000 in value, what i am looking for is what i get it in excel by LEN formula which count the number of character in string

Comment: Use a helper column.